# java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity

Tags: java, android, image, image-gallery

My application gets images from gallery in a Marshmallow device, but when I run it on a device with API level 18, I get the exception.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity
```

Here's my code for getting Permission;

```
private static final int SELECT_IMAGE = 1;

public void addImage(View view){


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23){

        ImagePicker();

    } else {

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);

        } else {

            ImagePicker();

        }

    }

}
```

Here's the intent for picking up the image;

```
 public void ImagePicker (){

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    intent.putExtra("crop", true);
    intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
    intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
    intent.putExtra("outputX", 400);
    intent.putExtra("outputY", 400);
    intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_IMAGE);

}
```

Here's the code for getting the result

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    profileImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profilePicture);

if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_CANCELED ) {

        if (requestCode == SELECT_IMAGE && data != null) {

           Bundle extra = data.getExtras(); 
            Bitmap image = extra.getParcable("data");
            profileImage.setImageBitmap(image);

        }

    }
```

Please help, Thanks.

Comment: Well, [`ACTION_PICK` does not take those extras, and `ACTION_PICK` does not return a `"data"` extra](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PICK). Beyond that, your code will not compile (typos) nor will it run (activity with invalid zero-argument constructor). If you want help, you will have better luck providing a [mcve], which would include the full Java stack trace associated with your crash, and the **actual code** (not fake code) that triggers that crash.

Comment: If that was the case then shouldn't my code also not work on a Marshmallow device?

Comment: Well, the code in your question does not work on a Marshmallow device. As I noted, it has syntax errors and logic errors, above and beyond whatever your specific problem is. But, let's pretend for a moment that the code that you are trying is not this code, but similar. In that case, perhaps for the one device that you tried, it has an `ACTION_PICK` that accepts those extras and returns a `"data"` extra. There are ~2 billion devices, across thousands of device models. Few will support that, because that lies outside the bounds of the documented behavior for `ACTION_PICK`.